# IE and jQuery posts are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

I'm trying to post to my backend with jQuery ajax, and it works in all browsers except internet explorer (ie 11).

Am i missing something for IE?

```
var example = "example/1234";

jQuery.post('#{test_path}', {
    uri: example
}, function(r) {
    if (r.status === 201) {  
      // success
    } else {
      // failure 
    }
});
```

my backed at test_path

```
def test
  render :json => {:status => 401}
end
```

**edit**: The code just hangs. The post never reaches my controller, console log remains blank and the network tab doesn't show any post information.

Comment: What does it do in Internet Explorer? Have you checked the Network and/or Console tabs in the F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: Why does it not work? What error is reported? Did the server respond with the expected header/data/contentType? did IE interpret it properly? did jQuery give a meaningful error reason in the ajaxError callback? What statuscode did jQuery report? what statuscode did the network tab report?

Comment: Console doesn't return anything, there is no post in the networks tab of internet explorer, nothing ever hit my controller

Comment: however the other browsers do a success post in the network tab

Comment: Add an error handler to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the uri (a string) as first parameter and not in that object, e. g.:

```
jQuery.post('/some/uri', {
    myPostDataKey: 'myPostDataValue'
}, function(r) {
    if (r.status === 201) {  
      // success
    } else {
      // failure 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats not an object... its a template variable of some sort that will/is being interpreted and likely evaluate to a uri. That said it is worth testing that the value being interpreted is what he expects it to be.

Comment: Please read what i actually wrote before downvoting. Apparently he put the desired uri into the object, which is passed as the second parameter. We'd need to see if the first parameter ist acutally rendered to an uri to see if your comment makes sense.

Comment: Ok, sorry then. Still, we can't be sure that '#{test_path}' is correctly rendered to a uri.

Comment: '#{test_path}'was not returning a url and chrome and firefox just posted somewhere and it happened to work where as internet explorer won't make that assumption i guess. I still haven't solved it but at least we identified the problem.

Comment: Probably your JavaScript is not rendered by your template language. If you desire variable uris, you could store them into custom data-Attributes on Elements (e. g. before rendering: <div id="uri" data-uri="#{my-uri}">) and in JS: var uri = $('#uri').attr('data-uri'); /*OR*/ var uri = $('#uri').data('uri');. Keep in mind that this is a very simplified example.